# How I can resolve Error when Building a image of Docker from eclipse

Tags: spring, docker

someone can help me, I'm using spring boot to build a image of docker but when I execute a command to build a image a get a error. I'm execute this command from eclipse (spring-build:build-image -DsinkTests) and obtained this error:

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/amarino.DOMINIOIDLSAS/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/amarino.DOMINIOIDLSAS/eclipse/jee-2020-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/amarino.DOMINIOIDLSAS/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/amarino.DOMINIOIDLSAS/eclipse/jee-2020-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------< com.in28minutes.microservices:currency-exchange-service >-------
[INFO] Building currency-exchange-service-kubernetes 0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:build-image (default-cli) > package @ currency-exchange-service >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Personales\spring-microservices-v2-main\05.kubernetes\currency-exchange-service\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\Personales\spring-microservices-v2-main\05.kubernetes\currency-exchange-service\target\test-classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.596 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-02T16:15:25-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project currency-exchange-service: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: share your pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `invalid target release: 15`.

That indicates that your pom.xml is configured to build for jdk15. Can it be that you are using an earlier version of java when copiling your classes.

Please try to build with jdk15 or newer.

If that is not possible to can change the configuration in your pom.xml to build for an older version of java than 15.

Comment: Good! :) If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark my answer as accepted. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I have marked it, only that due to my low ranking it does not show it